# Cleaning up data frame and date time

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, formatting

I am working with data frame. One of the columns contains date where the format of cell are mixed between date, time and string. The sample date frame is as follow:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Date'] = ['EPL','Sunday 21st April 2019','13:30:00','13:30:00','French Ligue 1','14:30:00']
df['Name'] = ['A','B','C','D','E','F']
```

I want to create a new column that contains the text of date column.
The expected output is as follows:

[image]

How can I do that?

Comment: first create function which you can run like `my_function("Sunday 21st April 2019")` and it will return `EPL`, the same with other arguments. Later you can use it with `df['Col'] = df['Date'].apply(my_funtion)`

Comment: Thanks for the advice. However, the date columns contains multiple date such as 21st,22nd,23rd April etc

Comment: so you have to create one function which can work with all values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC using `to_datetime`, the select the position return NaN, then `ffill`

```
df.loc[pd.to_datetime(df.Date,errors='coerce').isnull(),'col']=df.Date
df.col=df.col.ffill()
df
Out[867]: 
                     Date Name             col
0                     EPL    A             EPL
1  Sunday 21st April 2019    B             EPL
2                13:30:00    C             EPL
3                13:30:00    D             EPL
4          French Ligue 1    E  French Ligue 1
5                14:30:00    F  French Ligue 1
```